# Date and time formatting

Tags: android, datetime, datetime-format

I am working on a project in which I need to change the time to book order based on current time. What I need to do is I want to get the current time and have to generate a string list of time and populate them in spinner. eg. My start and end time are 11am to 2 pm and current time is 12.30 pm. So I need to take the current time and generate a list view of times of 30 mins gap till end time. So that will be 1:00,1:30,2:00.

```
public void doWork() {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            TextView txtCurrentTime= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbltime);
                Date dt = new Date();
                int hours = dt.getHours();
                int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                String curTime = hours + ":"+minute + ":"+ seconds;
                txtCurrentTime.setText(curTime);
        }catch (Exception e) {}
    }
});
}

class CountDownRunner implements Runnable{
// @Override
public void run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            try {
            doWork();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
 }
}
```

I have got this code from So which i can use to get current hours and min in hh:mm format. How to approach further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
List<String>timeslot=new ArrayList<String>();


    String stoptime="04:00 PM";
    String starttime="11:00 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    Date d1=null;
    Date d2=null;
    try 
    {
         d1=df1.parse(stoptime);
         d2=df1.parse(starttime);
    } 
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat df2=new SimpleDateFormat("kk");
    String curtime=df2.format(now.getTime());
    stoptime=df2.format(d1);
    starttime=df2.format(d2);
    tv.setText(df2.format(d1));
    tv2.setText(curtime);
    int t1=Integer.parseInt(stoptime);
    int t2=Integer.parseInt(curtime);
    int t3=Integer.parseInt(starttime);
    if(t2>=t3)
    {

    while(t2<t1)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat df4=new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        String curmin=df4.format(now.getTime());
        String stopmin=df4.format(d1);
        int t4=Integer.parseInt(curmin);
        if(t4<60)
        {
            int t5=60-t4;
            if(t5>30)
            {
                t5=t5-30;
            }
            now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, t5);
            SimpleDateFormat df3=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            curtime=df3.format(now.getTime());
            timeslot.add(curtime);

        }
        now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        SimpleDateFormat df3=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        curtime=df3.format(now.getTime());
        timeslot.add(curtime);
        curtime=df2.format(now.getTime());
        t2=Integer.parseInt(curtime);
    }
    tv3.setText(curtime);
    ArrayAdapter<String>aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, timeslot);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    timespin.setAdapter(aa);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have create a code logic for your problem , may be it is not fully implemented but near to your issue.
first I took calendar instance and then start a loop to check whether current hour is greater than 14 that is 2:00 PM then loop will continue to generate time and got incremented by 30 minute until it reaches to 2:00 PM

```
 Calendar c1 =Calendar.getInstance();
        String time=""+c1.getTime();
        System.out.println("time="+time);
        System.out.println("hr="+Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY+"min="+Calendar.MINUTE+"sec="+Calendar.SECOND+"am="+Calendar.AM_PM);
        while(c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)<=14)
        {
            String hr=""+c1.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            String mi=""+c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            String se=""+c1.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            String curTime = hr + ":"+mi + ":"+ se;
            System.out.println("time="+curTime);
            c1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but can u plz explain this a bit. I think u took the numbers in the query as hardcoded one ???

Comment: okie first I took caledar instance and then start a loop to check whether current time is greater than 2:00 PM then loop will continue  to geenarate time and got incremented by 30 minute until it reaches to 2:00 PM

Comment: need ur help frnd if possible gimmme ur email id.

Comment: you can come to chat of room Android

Comment: maneesh i m not authorised for android room. can v meet in android people room?

Comment: Then come to Android-People names room

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8438/discussion-between-samir-singh-and-maneesh)

Comment: thanks. Now i got a new solution that i can merge with urs to get my problem solved

Answer (score 1):

If want to display current Time on Application use **Digital Clock** it is in **Pallet->Time&Date->Digital-clock** it is a Text View with time changing continuously.No need to use timer or thread for that.answer for main problem: For that you can use Timer or Thread.Check Hour and Minute manually and  just do one thing to increase efficiency of your program.Take Boolean variable as flag set value to false.at start of program check Hour and Minute after each Minute.After getting the first one set that flag to True and then sleep that thread or timer to 30 minute.you will get better result.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SimpleDateFormat?

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss zzz").format(new Date(c1.getTime()));
```

Comment: Yeah i knw this but its not sufficient dude. need to go more into it

Comment: If you only need to get, the hour value or the minutes value from a given Calendar or Date or time in ms since Epoch, SimpleDateFormat takes care of it, there's no need to redo all that code.